# create a get api using Authorization token in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, token, access-token

i have a **registraion** api that register user details to database  it also genrates **token** using
**laravel passport**  and saves the token into database

now i am trying to create a **get api** that will fetch all data from database  using token generated

what i have tryed

in
**api.php**

`Route::get('/get_user', [userDEtails::class, 'get_user']);`

**userDEtails.php**  controler

```
public function get_user(Reqest $req)
{

// what code must i add here
    
}
```

**in post man i want to add token in  header as  Authorization  and api to work**

i am using Laravel Framework 9.41.0

[image]

[image]

Comment: What kind of relationship do you have setup already? There needs to be a relationship setup between the tokens generated table and the users table. Have you done anything towards that so far?

Comment: @Moudi i am not sure about that i am realy new to larvel here i will add some screenshot of my database

Comment: @Moudi let me know if u want any code or sceen shot of any file

Comment: Inside the user model and the API model did you setup relationships? hasOne etc...

Comment: no i have not created any

Comment: Have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships you need to have relationships set up on the model level, this will allow you to fetch objects related to others (In this case, you want to get the user based on his API KEY)

Comment: @Moudi can u be more specifc i am realy new to backend  a more clear answer would be helpfull

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250523/discussion-between-moudi-and-menu-cd).

Comment: @Moudi can u help

Comment: @menucd are you trying to get the user data from an authenticated token?

Comment: @menucd has your issue been resolved?

Answer (score 6):

Since you've said you're using Laravel Passport for this, try doing [this to get the user (and check scopes)](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#checking-scopes-on-a-token-instance)

```
public function get_user(Request $request)
{
    $user = $request->user();
}
```

This should ideally work. You will also need to make sure that your route is using the ['auth:api' middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#via-middleware) for your route like this -

```
Route::get('/get_user', [userDEtails::class, 'get_user'])->middleware('auth:api');
```

If for some reason you can't use the 'auth:api' middleware for this route, and need to stick with 'web' or something else, you can use -

```
$user = auth()->guard('api')->user()
```

OR

```
$user = $request->user('api')
```

instead to get the user object.

Answer (score 1):

To fetch the data from the database using the token generated, you can follow the steps below:
In your get_user function, first retrieve the token from the request header by      using the header method on the request object.

```
$token = $req->header('Authorization');
```

Then you can use the TokenRepository provided by Laravel Passport to retrieve the authenticated user associated with the token. You can get an instance of the TokenRepository by using the app helper function:

```
$tokenRepository = app(TokenRepository::class);
$user = $tokenRepository->find($token);
```

If the token is valid and an associated user is found, you can then use the User model to fetch the data from the database:

```
$users = User::all();
```

Lastly ,return the fetched data to the client by returning a JSON response

```
return response()->json($users);
```

But to take care of any unexpected error ,add some error handling in case the token is invalid or an associated user is not found.

Answer (score 0):

In `Auth::check()`, it will check token is valid or not. Based on that, it will return `true` or `false`.

```
public function get_user(Request $request)
{
    if (Auth::check()) {
        $users = User::all();
        return response()->json($users, 200);
    } else {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
    }
}
```

---

In addition, before you send a request to `get_user()`, write the `login()` method and get the access token. You can use [passport](https://www.toptal.com/laravel/passport-tutorial-auth-user-access) or [JWT](https://www.positronx.io/laravel-jwt-authentication-tutorial-user-login-signup-api/)

---

If you use a [Laravel passport](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport) can use `bearerToken()` to get the token and `Auth::checkToken()` to validate the token.